# Starcraft 2: Hotkey to go to previous selection?

Tags: starcraft-2

Is there a function/command/keyboard shortcut that takes you back to your previously selected unit(s)/building(s)?

I know that control-groups are possible and that it's best practice to have hotkeys for army/command centers/production facilities/etc (which I do) but my question is specifically about a "go to previous selection" function.

Seems like a pretty useful function/command and I'm probably overlooking something simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no "previous selection" option.

Comment: So so surprised to know this :(